# Bitmap.getPixel(j,i) returns wrong RGB values?

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, rgb

[image]
I am trying to get the RGB values of a pixel in a jpeg image. This is the screen shot of my original image from photoshop at 2020% magnification

i have made the image("trial.jpg") in Adobe my self, and put a few red, green and blue pixels in the image that is a (30,11) pixel grid that starts at 0,0(ie top Left corner).

here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 30; j++) 
   {
        int c = garage.getPixel(j,i);
        int red1 = Color.red(c);        
        int green1 = Color.green(c);
        int blue1 = Color.blue(c);

        Log.e("PIXEL",j + "/" + i +   "= Red: " + red1 +"  Green: " + green1 + " Blue: " + blue1);
    }
}
```

i check the log, but i get wrong RGB values. I know this cause i put Red(255,0,0), Blue(0,0,255)  and Green(0,255,0) in those particular squares(pixels).

Here is the log :

```
04-10 03:25:29.171:   0/0= Red: 255  Green: 7 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.171:   1/0= Red: 191  Green: 5 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.171:   2/0= Red: 64  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.171:   3/0= Red: 64  Green: 0 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.171:   4/0= Red: 190  Green: 0 Blue: 8
04-10 03:25:29.171:   5/0= Red: 190  Green: 0 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.175:   6/0= Red: 64  Green: 0 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.175:   7/0= Red: 64  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.175:   8/0= Red: 190  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.175:   9/0= Red: 190  Green: 5 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.175:   10/0= Red: 63  Green: 5 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.175:   11/0= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.175:   12/0= Red: 5  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.179:   13/0= Red: 6  Green: 0 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.179:   14/0= Red: 4  Green: 0 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.179:   15/0= Red: 4  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   16/0= Red: 4  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   17/0= Red: 64  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   18/0= Red: 186  Green: 12 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   19/0= Red: 185  Green: 13 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   20/0= Red: 61  Green: 5 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   21/0= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   22/0= Red: 2  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   23/0= Red: 4  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   24/0= Red: 6  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.179:   25/0= Red: 7  Green: 0 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.179:   26/0= Red: 9  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   27/0= Red: 9  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   28/0= Red: 7  Green: 0 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.179:   29/0= Red: 5  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.179:   0/1= Red: 191  Green: 5 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.179:   1/1= Red: 144  Green: 4 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.179:   2/1= Red: 49  Green: 3 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.179:   3/1= Red: 49  Green: 2 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.179:   4/1= Red: 143  Green: 1 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.179:   5/1= Red: 143  Green: 0 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.179:   6/1= Red: 48  Green: 0 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.179:   7/1= Red: 48  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   8/1= Red: 144  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   9/1= Red: 144  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   10/1= Red: 49  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   11/1= Red: 3  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   12/1= Red: 5  Green: 2 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.179:   13/1= Red: 6  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.179:   14/1= Red: 4  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.179:   15/1= Red: 3  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   16/1= Red: 4  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.179:   17/1= Red: 50  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.183:   18/1= Red: 140  Green: 9 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.183:   19/1= Red: 138  Green: 9 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.183:   20/1= Red: 46  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.183:   21/1= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.183:   22/1= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   23/1= Red: 3  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   24/1= Red: 4  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   25/1= Red: 5  Green: 0 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.187:   26/1= Red: 7  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   27/1= Red: 7  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   28/1= Red: 6  Green: 0 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   29/1= Red: 4  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   0/2= Red: 63  Green: 1 Blue: 8
04-10 03:25:29.187:   1/2= Red: 49  Green: 3 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.187:   2/2= Red: 20  Green: 6 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.187:   3/2= Red: 20  Green: 6 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.187:   4/2= Red: 49  Green: 4 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   5/2= Red: 47  Green: 2 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   6/2= Red: 16  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   7/2= Red: 17  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   8/2= Red: 51  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   9/2= Red: 52  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   10/2= Red: 21  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   11/2= Red: 6  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   12/2= Red: 6  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   13/2= Red: 5  Green: 5 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   14/2= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   15/2= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   16/2= Red: 6  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   17/2= Red: 21  Green: 3 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.187:   18/2= Red: 48  Green: 3 Blue: 9
04-10 03:25:29.187:   19/2= Red: 46  Green: 3 Blue: 10
04-10 03:25:29.187:   20/2= Red: 15  Green: 1 Blue: 8
04-10 03:25:29.187:   21/2= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.187:   22/2= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   23/2= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   24/2= Red: 1  Green: 1 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.187:   25/2= Red: 2  Green: 1 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.187:   26/2= Red: 3  Green: 3 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.187:   27/2= Red: 3  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   28/2= Red: 2  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   29/2= Red: 2  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   0/3= Red: 1  Green: 0 Blue: 10
04-10 03:25:29.187:   1/3= Red: 2  Green: 2 Blue: 8
04-10 03:25:29.187:   2/3= Red: 4  Green: 6 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.187:   3/3= Red: 3  Green: 7 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   4/3= Red: 1  Green: 5 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   5/3= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   6/3= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   7/3= Red: 1  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   8/3= Red: 3  Green: 0 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   9/3= Red: 4  Green: 0 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.187:   10/3= Red: 5  Green: 1 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.187:   11/3= Red: 5  Green: 3 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.187:   12/3= Red: 5  Green: 5 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   13/3= Red: 4  Green: 5 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   14/3= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.187:   15/3= Red: 3  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   16/3= Red: 5  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   17/3= Red: 5  Green: 2 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.187:   18/3= Red: 3  Green: 0 Blue: 13
04-10 03:25:29.187:   19/3= Red: 2  Green: 0 Blue: 15
04-10 03:25:29.187:   20/3= Red: 2  Green: 0 Blue: 9
04-10 03:25:29.187:   21/3= Red: 2  Green: 0 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.187:   22/3= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.187:   23/3= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.187:   24/3= Red: 0  Green: 0 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.187:   25/3= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.187:   26/3= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.187:   27/3= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.187:   28/3= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.187:   29/3= Red: 1  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   0/4= Red: 3  Green: 0 Blue: 9
04-10 03:25:29.187:   1/4= Red: 2  Green: 1 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.187:   2/4= Red: 2  Green: 4 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.187:   3/4= Red: 1  Green: 5 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   4/4= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.187:   5/4= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.191:   6/4= Red: 1  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.191:   7/4= Red: 1  Green: 2 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.191:   8/4= Red: 1  Green: 0 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.191:   9/4= Red: 1  Green: 1 Blue: 10
04-10 03:25:29.191:   10/4= Red: 1  Green: 5 Blue: 13
04-10 03:25:29.191:   11/4= Red: 1  Green: 6 Blue: 12
04-10 03:25:29.191:   12/4= Red: 1  Green: 4 Blue: 8
04-10 03:25:29.191:   13/4= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.191:   14/4= Red: 4  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.191:   15/4= Red: 5  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.191:   16/4= Red: 3  Green: 2 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.191:   17/4= Red: 3  Green: 2 Blue: 8
04-10 03:25:29.191:   18/4= Red: 6  Green: 0 Blue: 17
04-10 03:25:29.191:   19/4= Red: 8  Green: 0 Blue: 17
04-10 03:25:29.191:   20/4= Red: 8  Green: 0 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.191:   21/4= Red: 6  Green: 0 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.191:   22/4= Red: 2  Green: 1 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.191:   23/4= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.191:   24/4= Red: 0  Green: 0 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.191:   25/4= Red: 0  Green: 0 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.191:   26/4= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.191:   27/4= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.191:   28/4= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.191:   29/4= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.191:   0/5= Red: 3  Green: 63 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.191:   1/5= Red: 2  Green: 48 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.191:   2/5= Red: 0  Green: 18 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.191:   3/5= Red: 0  Green: 19 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.191:   4/5= Red: 0  Green: 49 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.191:   5/5= Red: 1  Green: 49 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.191:   6/5= Red: 3  Green: 18 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.195:   7/5= Red: 3  Green: 18 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.199:   8/5= Red: 1  Green: 48 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.199:   9/5= Red: 0  Green: 48 Blue: 10
04-10 03:25:29.199:   10/5= Red: 2  Green: 20 Blue: 14
04-10 03:25:29.199:   11/5= Red: 2  Green: 6 Blue: 13
04-10 03:25:29.199:   12/5= Red: 0  Green: 5 Blue: 9
04-10 03:25:29.199:   13/5= Red: 1  Green: 4 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.199:   14/5= Red: 4  Green: 2 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.199:   15/5= Red: 4  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   16/5= Red: 1  Green: 2 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.199:   17/5= Red: 2  Green: 17 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.199:   18/5= Red: 8  Green: 46 Blue: 14
04-10 03:25:29.199:   19/5= Red: 10  Green: 45 Blue: 13
04-10 03:25:29.199:   20/5= Red: 9  Green: 15 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.199:   21/5= Red: 6  Green: 0 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   22/5= Red: 2  Green: 0 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.199:   23/5= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.199:   24/5= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   25/5= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   26/5= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.199:   27/5= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.199:   28/5= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   29/5= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.199:   0/6= Red: 1  Green: 191 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   1/6= Red: 0  Green: 143 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   2/6= Red: 0  Green: 49 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   3/6= Red: 0  Green: 49 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   4/6= Red: 0  Green: 144 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.199:   5/6= Red: 2  Green: 143 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.199:   6/6= Red: 6  Green: 48 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   7/6= Red: 6  Green: 48 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   8/6= Red: 2  Green: 142 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   9/6= Red: 2  Green: 142 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.199:   10/6= Red: 6  Green: 48 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.199:   11/6= Red: 6  Green: 4 Blue: 6
04-10 03:25:29.199:   12/6= Red: 2  Green: 8 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.199:   13/6= Red: 0  Green: 8 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   14/6= Red: 1  Green: 5 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.199:   15/6= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   16/6= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   17/6= Red: 3  Green: 48 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   18/6= Red: 7  Green: 137 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.199:   19/6= Red: 9  Green: 136 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.199:   20/6= Red: 6  Green: 46 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.199:   21/6= Red: 4  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   22/6= Red: 1  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.199:   23/6= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   24/6= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   25/6= Red: 0  Green: 5 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.199:   26/6= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   27/6= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   28/6= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.199:   29/6= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.199:   0/7= Red: 0  Green: 192 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   1/7= Red: 0  Green: 144 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   2/7= Red: 2  Green: 48 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   3/7= Red: 2  Green: 48 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.199:   4/7= Red: 1  Green: 143 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   5/7= Red: 3  Green: 143 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   6/7= Red: 6  Green: 48 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   7/7= Red: 5  Green: 47 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.199:   8/7= Red: 2  Green: 142 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.199:   9/7= Red: 2  Green: 142 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   10/7= Red: 6  Green: 48 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   11/7= Red: 7  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   12/7= Red: 5  Green: 7 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   13/7= Red: 4  Green: 8 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   14/7= Red: 3  Green: 5 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   15/7= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   16/7= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   17/7= Red: 2  Green: 48 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   18/7= Red: 5  Green: 139 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   19/7= Red: 6  Green: 138 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.203:   20/7= Red: 4  Green: 47 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   21/7= Red: 2  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   22/7= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.203:   23/7= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.203:   24/7= Red: 0  Green: 5 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.203:   25/7= Red: 0  Green: 6 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   26/7= Red: 0  Green: 5 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   27/7= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   28/7= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   29/7= Red: 2  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   0/8= Red: 0  Green: 67 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.203:   1/8= Red: 1  Green: 50 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.203:   2/8= Red: 5  Green: 17 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.203:   3/8= Red: 6  Green: 16 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.203:   4/8= Red: 5  Green: 47 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.203:   5/8= Red: 4  Green: 48 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   6/8= Red: 3  Green: 17 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.203:   7/8= Red: 1  Green: 17 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   8/8= Red: 0  Green: 48 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   9/8= Red: 0  Green: 48 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   10/8= Red: 2  Green: 19 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   11/8= Red: 5  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   12/8= Red: 10  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   13/8= Red: 12  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   14/8= Red: 11  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   15/8= Red: 7  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   16/8= Red: 2  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   17/8= Red: 0  Green: 19 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   18/8= Red: 1  Green: 52 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   19/8= Red: 2  Green: 52 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.203:   20/8= Red: 1  Green: 18 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.203:   21/8= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.203:   22/8= Red: 0  Green: 0 Blue: 8
04-10 03:25:29.203:   23/8= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 8
04-10 03:25:29.203:   24/8= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   25/8= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   26/8= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   27/8= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   28/8= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   29/8= Red: 1  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.203:   0/9= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 5
04-10 03:25:29.203:   1/9= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 4
04-10 03:25:29.203:   2/9= Red: 5  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.203:   3/9= Red: 6  Green: 0 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.203:   4/9= Red: 6  Green: 0 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   5/9= Red: 4  Green: 0 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   6/9= Red: 1  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   7/9= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   8/9= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   9/9= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   10/9= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   11/9= Red: 3  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   12/9= Red: 9  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   13/9= Red: 12  Green: 0 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   14/9= Red: 11  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   15/9= Red: 7  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   16/9= Red: 2  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   17/9= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   18/9= Red: 1  Green: 7 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   19/9= Red: 1  Green: 8 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   20/9= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   21/9= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   22/9= Red: 1  Green: 0 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.207:   23/9= Red: 1  Green: 1 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.207:   24/9= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   25/9= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   26/9= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.207:   27/9= Red: 0  Green: 0 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.207:   28/9= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   29/9= Red: 1  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   0/10= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   1/10= Red: 0  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   2/10= Red: 1  Green: 2 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   3/10= Red: 3  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   4/10= Red: 6  Green: 0 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   5/10= Red: 5  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   6/10= Red: 1  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.207:   7/10= Red: 0  Green: 4 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   8/10= Red: 2  Green: 6 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.207:   9/10= Red: 2  Green: 6 Blue: 7
04-10 03:25:29.207:   10/10= Red: 0  Green: 5 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.207:   11/10= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   12/10= Red: 3  Green: 2 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.207:   13/10= Red: 4  Green: 2 Blue: 3
04-10 03:25:29.207:   14/10= Red: 3  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.207:   15/10= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.211:   16/10= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.211:   17/10= Red: 1  Green: 1 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.211:   18/10= Red: 5  Green: 4 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.211:   19/10= Red: 5  Green: 5 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.211:   20/10= Red: 1  Green: 3 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.211:   21/10= Red: 0  Green: 2 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.211:   22/10= Red: 1  Green: 0 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.211:   23/10= Red: 1  Green: 0 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.211:   24/10= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.211:   25/10= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 0
04-10 03:25:29.211:   26/10= Red: 0  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.211:   27/10= Red: 1  Green: 1 Blue: 2
04-10 03:25:29.211:   28/10= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 1
04-10 03:25:29.211:   29/10= Red: 2  Green: 3 Blue: 1
```

I tried by saving it in 8bitJpeg... and 16bitJpeg... but Values i am getting are wrong. Can someone please help me, and explain me why is this happening?

for example the 4thRow, 1st pixel(ie 0,3) is Green= 0,255,0.

but its log says "0/3= Red: 1  Green: 0 Blue: 10"

Comment: can you show the logcat output?

Comment: Hi Amit, i have re edited my question, with the image and log. please let me know if you can find out whats going wrong. Hope this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to crack what was the main puzzling part in the problem.

1. the saving of a jpeg via different compression methods changes your RGB content of what you had set your pixels to. Hence safer with a lossless format like .png
2. a full zoom in on the image in PS shows many small grids. So though it says 30x11.. it actually is double. so that means double in length and double in width.
   So the real image i made in pixels was 60x22. So obviously what i saw on the Grid as the (0,3)GREEN, was actually 4 pixels on the real image at  (0,6) (0,7) (1,6) (1,7)